# t.test in r seems to give the wrong t value

Tags: r

I am performing a t test to determine if there is a difference in means between two paired vectors:

```
 s1 <- c(68, 74, 66.5, 69, 68, 71, 70, 70, 67, 68, 70 )
 s2 <- c(66.8, 73.9, 66.1, 67.2, 67.9, 69.4, 69.9, 68.6, 67.9,67.6, 68.8 )
```

When I run the t test:

```
t.test(s1,s2,paired = TRUE)
```

I get a result of:

```
data:  s1 and s2
t = 2.7014, df = 10, p-value = 0.02226
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.1178512 1.2276033

sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              0.6727273
```

I cant figure out where the tvalue of 2.7014 comes from.  If I look up the tvalue in a ttable for df = 10 and a two tailed test at 95% ci I get 2.228.

Comment: That t value is a calculated statistic based on your data, not a quantile from the t distribution.  You can replicate the calculation "by hand" by dividing the mean of the differences by the standard error of the differences (sd(diff)/sqrt(n)).

Comment: `mean(s1 - s2) / sqrt( var(s1 - s2) / (length(s1)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The t-value that R reports is that t-stat of your data. In other words, you get that value whether you look up the critical value of $2.228$ or not.

The critical value, however, is the value of $t$ you must exceed in order to reject the null hypothesis with at the $0.05$-level.

You would hope to have a t-value exceeding the critical value!